# Нам дано рациональное число double. Как выяснить, периодическое оно или нет? - Приближение непрерывными (цепными) дробями

Tags: c++, математика

Нам дано **рациональное** число `double`. Как выяснить, периодическое оно или нет?

Comment: Вы про [периодические десятичные дроби](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C#.D0.9F.D0.B5.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.B5.D1.81.D0.BA.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D0.B5.D1.81.D1.8F.D1.82.D0.B8.D1.87.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5_.D0.B4.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B8)?

Comment: Любое рациональное число является периодическим. Но что имеется в виду под словосочетанием «рациональное число `double`» — решительно непонятно.

Comment: число double не может содержать бесконечное колво чисел, т.к. ограничено надо выяснить есть ли у него период или нет элементарно

Comment: период 0 не считается

Comment: @D-side даааааа

Comment: Тип `double` не имеет возможности представлять числа с периодом отличным от `(0)` в любой системе счисления, основание которой делиться на два.

Comment: @PetSerAl и вы только что ответили на вопрос в комментарии. Оформите ответ что ли :)

Comment: @PetSerAl если бы оно само представлялось я бы не спрашивал =/

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Вас интересовал случай 1/14...

Answer (score 5):

"Внутри" `double` хранится в системе счисления с основанием `2`, а поскольку `10 = 2 * 5`, любое число, представимое конечной двоичной дробью, может быть представлено и конечной десятичной.

Соответственно, начиная с некоторого момента бесконечная десятичная запись любого числа, представимого типом `double`, будет состоять исключительно из нулей, что подходит под определение бесконечной последовательности с периодом 1. Поэтому:

```
bool is_periodic(double x) {
  return true;
}
```

**Но есть нюанс**: в это не вписываются бесконечности и NaN. Поскольку вещественными числами они не являются, я эти случаи не рассматривал.

Comment: емае 1/3 = 0,(3) - бесконечная периодическая, 1/2 = 0,5(0) - не считаем бесконечной!!!

Comment: @Роберт 0.(3) непредставимо в `double` :) Если 0.5(0) "не считается", то это уже ваше игрушечное определение, для которого ответ всегда "нет, не является".

Comment: 1/3 в дабл выглядит как 0,3333333333333000000000012351681687, а 1/2 как 0,500000000000000003215126612. Так что можно отличить!!!

Comment: @Роберт 1/3 в `double` с идеальной точностью **не представляется**. Вот совсем никак.

Comment: а я с иделаьной точностью написал? идут тройки потом куча нулей а потом мусор

Comment: @Роберт ...и это не 1/3 :)

Comment: >вещественными числами они не являются - омг

Comment: кароче ясно всё

Comment: @Роберт `1/3=0.333333333333333314829616256247` никаких нулей между тройками и мусором нет. `1/2=0.5` ровно без каких-либо погрешностей.

Comment: @PetSerAl выведите 100 знаков после запятой

Comment: @Роберт математически это 0.5000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000. Что выведет иное, содержит баг. Так бывает.

Comment: @Роберт *выведите 100 знаков после запятой* `1/3=0.3333333333 3333331482 9616256247 3909929394 7219848632 8125000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000 0000000000`, а как будет 1/2 Вам уже D-side написал.

Comment: @Роберт: срочно читайте, как устроены числа типа `double`. Никаких 100 знаков после запятой там нет. Это конечные двоичные дроби.

Answer (score 0):

Любое число double является конечной десятичной дробью (за исключением экзотики типа NaN) и поэтому - рациональным числом.

Поэтому вопрос может стоять только о **приближении** этой десятичной дроби другим рациональным числом, для чего применяются [цепные дроби](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C) вида
.[image: цепная дробь]
Величины **a<sub>i</sub>** называют *неполными частными*.

Если исходное число имеет вид **p/q**, то в соответствии с алгоритмом Евклида
**p<sub>0</sub>=p**, **q<sub>0</sub>=q**, **a<sub>0</sub> =[p<sub>0</sub>/q<sub>0</sub>]**,
**p<sub>i+1</sub>=q<sub>i</sub>**, **q<sub>i+1</sub>=p<sub>i</sub>-a<sub>i</sub>q<sub>i</sub>**, **a<sub>i+1</sub> =[p<sub>i+1</sub>/q<sub>i+1</sub>]**.
Если **q<sub>i+1</sub>=1**, то итерация была последней.

Разложение в цепную дробь - источник наилучших приближений для любой дроби. Эти приближения получаются, если использовать несколько первых неполных частных.

Если считать последним неполное частное **a<sub>k</sub>**, то получим:
**q<sub>k</sub>=a<sub>k</sub>**, **q<sub>i-1</sub>=a<sub>i-1</sub>q<sub>i</sub>+1**, **P=q<sub>0</sub>**, **Q=q<sub>1</sub>**.

Полученная таким образом дробь P/Q называется *подходящей*.

Возникает вопрос: c какого момента неполные частные не принимать в расчёт? Ответ понятен из следующего примера.
Пусть (с точностью до способа записи) double = 0.0714285714285714 (15 знаков).
Тогда: **p<sub>0</sub>=714285714285714**, **q<sub>0</sub>=100000000000000000**, **a<sub>0</sub>=0**;
**p<sub>1</sub>=q<sub>0</sub>=100000000000000000**, **q<sub>1</sub>=714285714285714**, **a<sub>1</sub>=[p<sub>1</sub>/q<sub>1</sub>]=14** (и равно [1/double]),
**p<sub>2</sub>=q<sub>1</sub>=714285714285714**, **q<sub>1</sub>=14**, **a<sub>2</sub>=[p<sub>1</sub>/q<sub>1</sub>]=51020408163265**.

Неполное частное **a<sub>2</sub>** оказалось совсем большим, а обратная ему величина - пренебрежимо малой. Это и есть ответ: следует удалять неполные частные, начиная с наибольшего, имеющего индекс больше 1.

Ограничиваясь первой подходящей дробью, получаем:
**q<sub>1</sub>=**a<sub>1</sub>=14**, **q<sub>0</sub>=0*14+1=0**,
**P/Q = 1/14**.

Как и всякая дробь со знаменателем, который не делит степень десятки, полученная дробь является периодической:

**1/14 = 0.0(714285)**.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, может что не так понял. Но у автора не дробь, а один `double`. И он очень хочет узнать, есть ли у него период, или нет. Не могли бы вы показать, какая часть вашего ответа ответила на вопрос ТС? Простите за тавтологию.

Comment: Есть объект - рациональное число. И у него есть такое свойство - представление в формате double (согласно стандарту и протчая). И автору хочется знать, безвозвратно ли утрачено его нативное представление как дроби с небольшими числителем и знаменателем.

Comment: А в какой части своего вопроса он спросил про начальное состояние дроби? Всё, что я вижу в его вопросе это то, что нужно из `double` понять является ли число периодическим или нет. P.S. минус не мой

Comment: LEQADA Я не вижу иного содержания в заголовке "есть **рациональное** число double"

Comment: Любое рациональное число, знаменатель которого не есть степень десятки, является периодической десятичной дробью. Но чтобы определить этот период, нужно знать её числитель и знаменатель. Мне записать это в ответ? :)

Comment: Мне кажется, что ответ из этого только и должен состоять. Один `double` сам по себе не является бесконечным. Поэтому не имеет даже смысла говорить о периодичности. Вы поставили сами себе задачу и решили её. Но вы не ответили на вопрос ТС.

Comment: @LEQADA Благодарю за конструктивное обсуждение и ценный совет.