# Период дроби double

Tags: c++

Как по заданному `double` определить, есть ли у его десятичного представления период !=0?

Comment: двоичный или десятичный?

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov любой !=0

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, прозрачный шар подсказывает мне, что автору нужен десятичный период

Comment: в двоичной и десятичной системах счисления периоды разные. 0.1 - периодическая дробь в двоичной системе счисления.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov  значит в десятичной

Comment: В следующий раз постарайтесь выражаться точнее.

Comment: "10-12 последних десятичных цифр числа образуют периодическую последовательность" - нет, нельзя.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov этот вопрос - полный дубликат вопроса от того же автора, заданного вчера. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470322/

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov и вы про это знаете (т.к на предыдущий вопрос отвечали). зачем править и переоткрывать явный дубликат?

Comment: @PashaPash, эм.. а зачем закрывать дубликат как "требует правки"? Я, например, того вопроса не видел.

Comment: @PashaPash, в любом случае, у этого есть принятый ответ, так что закрывать надо тот, наверное?

Comment: @Qwertiy закрыли скорее всего из очереди. Ответ в этом вопросе - неверен. Формулировка вопроса по факту подогнана под ответ автором ответа. Причем так, что второй - хороший ответ - теперь вроде как не в тему. Отметка об ответе поставлена топикастером по просьбе того же автора - "чтобы не удалили". Это тупо вандализм.

Comment: @Qwertiy я откатил правку. Пусть топикастер сам придет т сформулирует вопрос. Подгонять под свой ответ - недопустимо.

Comment: @PashaPash Уж не знаю, придёт ли он теперь... Но ответ его устроил, так что не понимаю этого действа.

Comment: @PashaPash Жду Вас здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/470322/%D0%94%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BE-double/470531#470531

Comment: @PashaPash Фраза 'Отметка об ответе поставлена топикастером по просьбе того же автора - "чтобы не удалили". Это тупо вандализм.' тенденциозна и легко опровергается. Признайте свою ошибку и извинитесь.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov ок, был неправ. Тем не менее - подгонка вопроса под свой ответ недопустима. Особенно если она меняет суть вопроса. Вам стоило явно дать ссылку на первый вопрос и предложить автору ответить на него. А не править дубликат

Comment: @PashaPash OK. Полагаю, ТС не появится.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

1. Перевести число в десятичную строку, удалить десятичную точку и ведущие нули.
2. Прибавляя и вычитая 5 к последнему знаку (с переносом), отбросить последний знак, после чего развернуть строчки в обратном порядке.
3. Для каждой из полученных строк str1 и str2 в цикле по k проверить составное условие вида
   `(substr.str(k) == substr.str(k,k)) && (substr.str(k) == substr.str(2*k,k)) && ...`

Количество простых условий внутри составного - определяется количеством повторов, возможных для данного периода.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32295/discussion-on-answer-by-yuri-negometyanov---double).

Answer (score 11):

В double нельзя хранить периодические дроби, точка.
В double число хранится с помощью двух целых чисел `f` и `e`, так что число равно

```
(1+f*2^-52)*2^(e-1023)
```

Там нет никакого "признака периодичности".

При записи периодической дроби в double она округляется до не-периодической.
Если в double записано 0.3333, - это число 0.3333(0). Оно могло быть изначально 0.3333(3), или 0.3333(2), или 0.3333(1), или 0.3333000(123), но Вы никогда об этом не узнаете - периодическая часть безвозвратно потеряна.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32294/discussion-on-answer-by-abyx---double).

Answer (score 1):

Если первоначально даны два целых числа - делимое и делитель, а не просто их частное, то можно провести операции, аналогичные школьному делению "в столбик", остаток на каждом этапе нужно сохранять. Если остаток встретится повторно, значит частное содержит периодическую дробь.